# Intercept property setter in groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I intercept a dynamic property setter in groovy ?

Here's what I have tried:

```
def a = new Object ()
a.metaClass.setx = { newValue ->
   print "new value is ${newValue}"
}
a.x = 3
```

I want the code above to print "new value is 3"

Answer (score 1):

The setter method in your example should be named `setX`, e.g.

```
def a = new Object ()
a.metaClass.setX = { newValue ->
   print "new value is ${newValue}"
}
a.x = 3
```

This is a Java convention that defines a pattern for `setX` and `getX` methods - a class property name part starts with capital letter. It means that if you want to intercept a setter method for a field named `firstName`, a setter method that Groovy compiler creates is called `setFirstName(name)`.

Comment: Are you sure this works ? It doesn't appear to print "new value is 3" in groovyconsole.appspot.com

Comment: Yes, it works like that - https://asciinema.org/a/6xRBBixiW3ZhLHpayuS3aT9el I don't know why groovyconsole.appspot.com executes it differently.

Comment: It seems like this is groovyconsole.appspot.com bug. Take a look what adding `println "test"` causes - https://i.imgur.com/yj6t13L.png

Comment: Actually, it's working all right. It just shows the "Result" tab by default (which in groovy, unless you `return` something manually, will be the last assignment). If you keep your initial code, execute and switch to the "Output" tab, you'll see it did work.

Comment: Thanks @sensei for point that out - I missed the "Output" tab :O

Answer (score 0):

Groovy only creates the synthetic accessor (setter method) if there isn't a defined implementation.

If you create a setX method in the Object, that will do what you're trying to do. The first answer is technically correct but reflection is a powerful tool to be handled carefully, and shouldn't be used where it's not needed.